# How to use HTTP Basic Auth as separate FastAPI service?

Tags: python, authentication, microservices, basic-authentication, fastapi

**What I want to achieve?** Have one service responsible for HTTP Basic Auth (access) and two services (a, b) where some endpoints are protected by access service.

**Why?** In scenario where there will be much more services with protected endpoints to not duplicate [authorize function](https://github.com/ethru/http_basic_example/blob/master/example-service/app/main.py#L12-L21) in each service. Also to do modification in one place in case of changing to OAuth2 (maybe in future).

**What I did?**
I followed guide on [official website](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/) and created [example service](https://github.com/ethru/http_basic_example/blob/master/example-service/app/main.py) which works totally fine.

**Problem** occurs when I try to move authorization to separate [service](https://github.com/ethru/http_basic_example/blob/master/access-service/app/main.py) and then use it within few other
services with protected endpoints. I can't figure out how to do it. Could you please help me out?

I have tried different functions setup. Nothing helped, so far my code looks like this:

**access-service**

```
import os
import secrets

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

security = HTTPBasic()


def authorize(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    is_user_ok = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.username, os.getenv('LOGIN'))
    is_pass_ok = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.password, os.getenv('PASSWORD'))

    if not (is_user_ok and is_pass_ok):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail='Incorrect email or password.',
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic'},
        )


app = FastAPI(openapi_url="/api/access/openapi.json", docs_url="/api/access/docs")


@app.get('/api/access/auth', dependencies=[Depends(authorize)])
def auth():
    return {"Granted": True}
```

**a-service**

```
import httpx
import os

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status

ACCESS_SERVICE_URL = os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL')

app = FastAPI(openapi_url="/api/a/openapi.json", docs_url="/api/a/docs")


def has_access():
    result = httpx.get(os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL'))
    if result.status_code == 401:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail='No access to resource. Login first.',
        )


@app.get('/api/a/unprotected_a')
async def unprotected_a():
    return {"Protected": False}


@app.get('/api/a/protected_a', dependencies=[Depends(has_access)])
async def protected_a():
    return {"Protected": True}


@app.get('/api/a/protected_b', dependencies=[Depends(has_access)])
async def protected_b():
    return {"Protected": True}
```

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that, when you are calling Service_A with credentials it's making a call to the Access_Service in the has_access() function.

If you look closely,

```
result = httpx.get(os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL'))
```

You are simply making a GET call without forwarding the credentials as headers for this request to the Access_Service.

Rewrite your has_access() in all the services to

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import Header 

def has_access(authorization: Optional[str] = Header(None)):
    if not authorization:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail='No access to resource. Credentials missing!',
    )
    headers = {'Authorization': authorization}
    result = httpx.get(os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL'), headers=headers)
    if result.status_code == 401:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail='No access to resource. Login first.',
        )
```

Inside your access service you have mistakenly typed True as true,

```
@app.get('/api/access/auth', dependencies=[Depends(authorize)])
def auth():
    return {"Granted": True}
```

I have cloned your repo and tested it, it's working now. Please check and confirm.

[EDIT] Swagger does not allow authorization header for basic auth (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/612)

Work-Around (not recommended)

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

security = HTTPBasic()

def has_access(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security), authorization: Optional[str] = Header(None)):
```

Comment: Thank you for taking look at it. I have checked your answer, but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'`. Here is updated [repo](https://github.com/ethru/http_basic_example/tree/answer),

Comment: Where are you making the API call from, browser or Postman?

Comment: I'm making it from browser. I'm using Swagger UI at http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/a/docs

Comment: @Ethr - I have updated the code, the error is happening because while calling Service_A you are not entering the credentials, I was able to reproduce it!

Comment: @Ether - http://localhost:8080/api/a/docs#/default/protected_a_api_a_protected_a_get - you need to place the authorization string here before clicking Execute.

Comment: What form this string should have? I have tried: user@password, {"user": "password"}, but it still throws error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224755/discussion-between-soumojit-ghosh-and-ethr).

Comment: For example, if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and OpenSesame as the password, then the field's value is the Base64 encoding of Aladdin:OpenSesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l. Then the Authorization header will appear as:

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Soumojit Ghosh answer and [FastAPI Issue 1037](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1037) I figured out how should I modify my code. **a-service** after changes:

```
import httpx
import os

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Header, HTTPException, status
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasicCredentials, HTTPBearer

security = HTTPBearer()

ACCESS_SERVICE_URL = os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL')

app = FastAPI(openapi_url="/api/a/openapi.json", docs_url="/api/a/docs")


def has_access(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    response = httpx.get(os.getenv('ACCESS_SERVICE_URL'), headers={'Authorization': credentials.credentials})
    if response.status_code == 401:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401)


@app.get('/api/a/unprotected_a')
async def unprotected_a():
    return {"Protected": False}


@app.get('/api/a/protected_a', dependencies=[Depends(has_access)])
async def protected_a():
    return {"Protected": True}


@app.get('/api/a/protected_b', dependencies=[Depends(has_access)])
async def protected_b():
    return {"Protected": True}
```

Now header can be sent through SwaggerUI. Click Authorize and then enter it in Value field. To generate your header from login and password you can use for example [this tool](https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/). It will look like: `Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=`.

Comment: @laplace its access service url - http://access_service:8000/api/access/auth . Application was built with docker-compose. That url was added as environment variable.